# How to convert Flux<List<Object>> into Mono<List<Object>>

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a service which returns `Flux<List<Integer>>` and I would like to convert it into `Mono<List<Integer>>` to be used inside `transform()`

Here is what I did by using `flatMap` and `Mono.just()`:

```
private Mono<List<Integer>> filterAndMap(Mono<List<Integer>> listMono) {
  return listMono.filter(integers -> integers.size() == 3)
      .map(integers -> integers.stream()
          .map(integer -> integer * 10)
          .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}

void method1() {
  Flux.just(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6), Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9, 10))
      .flatMap(integers -> this.filterAndMap(Mono.just(integers)))
      .doOnNext(System.out::println)
      .blockLast();
}
```

But what I would like is to use `transform` instead:

```
void method2() {
  Flux.just(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6), Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9, 10))
      .convertFluxToMono()?
      .transform(this::filterAndMap)
      .doOnNext(System.out::println)
      .block();
}
```

Is there any operator or technique to make method2 to work?
As a result I expect `onNext()` be called 2 times each with value of List

I know filterAndMap method could be simplified and be used without any complication but actual method is huge(just modified for clarity) and there are many operators in a chain that I want to reuse by avoiding duplications.

**Update:**

A little bit context what I want to achieve.
I have 2 services - one via Http which returns me `Mono<List<Integer>>` and another one via Redis which returns `Flux<List<Integer>>`.
For both cases I have the exact same functionality - chain of 10-15 operators and what I want to achieve is to avoid duplicate code.

For example:

```
  void f1() {
    Mono<List<Integer>> mono = getFromHttp();
    
    mono
        .map(integers -> integers.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity())))
        .filter(entry -> entry.size() > 5)
        //...
        //many other operators
        //...
        //.flatMap()
        //.switchIfEmpty()
        //.doOnNext()
        .retryWhen();
  }

  void f2() {
    Flux<List<Integer>> flux = getFromRedis();
    
    flux.
        //...
        //same functionality here
        //...
  }
```

Maybe better to not concentrate to convert Flux to Mono but instead convert Mono to Flux which I guess much easier?

**Update2:**

I have changed my existing filterAndMap into Flux.
And instead of converting Flux to Mono I went with Mono to Flux

now I can call `Flux.transform(this::filterAndMap)` and `Mono.transform(mono -> this.filterAndMap(mono.flux()))` accordingly

```
private Flux<List<Integer>> filterAndMap(Flux<List<Integer>> listMono) {
  return listMono.filter(integers -> integers.size() == 3)
      .map(integers -> integers.stream()
          .map(integer -> integer * 10)
          .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Thanks @Michael Berry, even I have changed the implementation, your solution fully covers my initial question/issue. So I accept it.

And thanks to @Simon Baslé for a good call, I have redesign my transformer and went with safer approach(Mono to Flux)

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here - `transform()` is available on a flux as well, why are you trying to convert it to a mono? (the first method isn't really converting it to a mono either, you're just wrapping up each element of the flux into a mono before using `flatMap`, when you'd be better just using `map`.) Appreciate this is a cut down example, but I think we need some more context to work out what your aim is.

Comment: Yes, I did it with purpose to show the way I have implemented Mono.just(), is not what I want. I have updated the post. `transform` is not a requirement I just didn't find other operator which will help to reuse some peace of code written in reactive. What I want is to use same functionality both for Mono and Flux, because the data I receive exactly the same and functionality I'm going to use is also the same.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. So you want the same transformation applied to `Mono` and `Flux` without code duplication?

Comment: you have to be extra careful with this idea. Applying an arbitrary Flux transform function to a Mono is indeed possible, but if you want the output to be a Mono, then you need to think about what happens if the Flux result of the transformation DOES produce more than one `onNext`. `next()` is a viable approach only if it is ok to drop extraneous elements in that case

Comment: thanks @Simon Baslé, I guess I met your mentioned issue and seems what I wanted is kind of non sense and probably better convert Mono to Flux instead of vice versa. And in that case it will be safe?

Comment: probably safer that way yeah if you want a common type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, taking the question here as "How do I apply the same transformation to both a `Mono` and a `Flux` without duplicating the code?"

You could use a simple utility function like so:

```
static <T> Function<Mono<T>, Mono<T>> toMonoTransformer(
    Function<Flux<T>, Flux<T>> transformer) {
  return listMono -> transformer.apply(listMono.flux()).next();
}
```

This function can then be used on any transformer of any type. You can then use the transformation function as-is for a Flux:

```
void method2() {
  Flux.just(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6), Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9, 10))
      .transform(this::filterAndMap)
      .doOnNext(System.out::println)
      .blockLast();
}
```

...and applying a quick utility method for the `Mono`:

```
void method1() {
  Mono.just(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
      .transform(toMonoTransformer(this::filterAndMap))
      .doOnNext(System.out::println)
      .block();
}
```

Comment: thanks @michael-berry , even though the idea is clear for me, I still can't make it work. Could you please check `toMonoTransformer` again? because filterAndMap accepts Mono and returns Mono `private Mono<List<Integer>> filterAndMap(Mono<List<Integer>> listMono)`. Btw, for method2 `.transform(listFlux -> this.filterAndMap(listFlux.next()))` works, but produces only one element. I want all 3 items, like listOfLists -> forEachList -> convertToMono() -> transform(convertedMono)

Comment: @Serg You'd need to change `filterAndMap()` so it accepts a `Flux` (which should be trivial.) And you only need to use the `toMonoTransformer` method where you're transforming a `Mono` - otherwise just use `.transform(this::filterAndMap)` without the utility function.